# Blinking text on mouseover

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

How to get rid of blinking text on mouseover in javascript. I edited the number of duration but doesn't make any different. It doesn't look smooth to me at all. I'm quite a new web developer, not sure what in javascript code need to be edited it right. By the way what I want to achieve is when the page first load, the texts will be hidden until mouseover, 2 lines will be revealed and onmouseout texts will be disappeared again (blinking text appears at onmouseover all the time), then when onclick to call another function, fancybox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".msg-link").hover(
            function(){
                var id = $(this).data("id");
                    if(id!==undefined){
                        $("#" + id).show();   
                    }
                        $("#textMessages").show();

                    },function(){
                    $("#textMessages").hide();
                    $(".hidden").hide();
                });
            });

            function ShowHide() {
                alert('here');
                $("#textMessages").animate({
                    "height": "toggle"
                }, {
                    duration: 1000
                });
                }
</script> 

<div>
    <img class="msg-link" data-id="test" src="1.png" alt="" />
       <p id="textMessages">test<br />
        <a class="hidden" id="test" href="1.png" rel="group1" title="example title text">More View</a>
        <a class="hidden" id="koya" href="2.png" rel="group1" title="more text right here"></a>
       </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need to explain this better. It seems to behave just as you describe to me. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/SRLj9/

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this was an animation focused questions you wanted a smooth show/hide type of animation? Imo You actually should use fadeIn or fadeOut for ultimate smootheness imo.  but you can set the time on the show() hide() if that is what you really prefer.. or you can combine fadein and altering the height of the parent element so it gives a bit of an opening effect but not the jagged scaling from the left and down effect.

(+) added an "id" to the parent div you probably don't want the link disappearing when you scroll off the image if you went through all that effort to show it.

I modified mrtsherman's example to what I thought you were trying to say.  I'm sure it could be a bit more dynamic as you were trying to do. BUT this was an animation or effect question I'm assuming? right?

http://jsfiddle.net/SRLj9/9/